# How to prevent Client DOM XSS vulnerability <loadXML> in javascript?

Tags: dom

Method function at line 200 of .../js/general.js gets user input for the
data element. This element’s value then flows through client-side code without being properly sanitized or
validated and is eventually displayed to the user in loadXML at line 241 of / .../js/general.js. This may enable a DOM XSS attack.

Script as follows:

```
 success: function(data){
    var xmlObj = loadXML(data);
    ........}

    function loadXML(xmlString){

        xmlString = xmlString.replace(/^\s*|\s(?=\s)|\s*$/g, "");
        xmlString = xmlString.replace(/(&)(?!amp;)/gi, "&amp;");

        try{ 
            xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.async="false";
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString);
        }catch(e){
            try{ 
                parser=new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
            }catch(e){
                alert(e.message);
                return;
            }
        }
        return xmlDoc.documentElement;
    }
```

The possibility of DOM XSS attack may be at xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlString).
Could some help me how to sanitize the above scenario to satisfy Checkmarx?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can anyone help me solve this please?

Comment: I edited you question once to remove the `javascript` tag. I see you put it back. This is not a `javascript` or a `jquery` question. I doubt that it has anything to do with `html` either. Maybe if you stop spamming tags at it, you might get some help from the poeple who know what it's actually about.